# instalando Django em uma venv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Estou tentando instalar a mais recente versão do Django (1.9.6) na minha virtualenv, porém quando uso o comando pip install django, dentro do ambiente virtual, recebo o seguinte retorno:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django==1.9.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: Olha cara, você tem certeza que o ambiente virtual está ativado? Ele está dizendo que o django já está na última versão. Porém, essa última versão se encontra em uma pasta do sistema e não em um ambiente virtual.

Comment: Entre na `venv` usando o codigo `source /venv/bin/activate`. Caso ja estiver na virtualenv poste o que retorna no `pip freeze`

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem diz para você usar `--upgrade` no comando, pois o Django já está instalado.

Use:

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

Assim a antiga versão será substituída pela mais recente